# i want the user to input a string in the format [1 2 3,4 5 6,7 8 9] and convert it to a 2d float array without knowing the number of rows and columns

Tags: c++, arrays, string, matrix

i tried to use the strtok function but it requires me to provide the number of rows and columns

```cpp
void getvalues(char* t,float** v, int n, int m)
{
    char* c;
    c = strtok(t, "[ ,");
    while (c != NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                v[i][j] = atof(c);
                c = strtok(0, "[ ,");               
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}

int main()
{

    float** matrix1 = new float* [100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        matrix1[i] = new float[100];

    float** matrix2 = new float* [100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        matrix2[i] = new float[100];

    float** matrix3 = new float* [100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        matrix3[i] = new float[100];

    int n, m,r ,f;
    char s[999];
    char d[999];
    char choice;

    cin.getline(s, 999);
    getvalues(s, matrix1, n, m);
```

Comment: If you don't know the number or rows and columns, how would you know when a new row starts?

Comment: Your `float**` stuff looks fishy. This is C++ don't write as if it was C.

Comment: There is no need for hardcoded values such as `100`, `999`, etc. if you were to actually use idiomatic C++.  The code looks like `C`, with the only difference being `new[]`.

Comment: that's the problem i don't, i am only given the string and based on that string i am supposed to know the number of rows and columns and convert it to a 2d array

Comment: @AbdelrahmanHassan The way the code should be written would look very little like the attempt you've tried.   That is just to warn you that whatever answer is posted, get ready for a vast change to what you've written.

Comment: I would take a very different approach to this. For starters, use `std::vector<std::vector<float>>`. And then read the whole user input from `'['` to `']'` into a `std::string` in a single operation, then split the input on `','` to determine the rows, and then split each row on `' '` to determine the columns, pushing each row and column into the `vector`s as needed.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue in `C++`, the C library function `strtok()` as well as
character arrays `char*` shouldn't be used.
Better use the `vector` container from the C++ STL, which can hold dynamical data
and takes care about the memory allocation/deallocation, hence garbage collection.

The final matrix shall be stored in `vector<vector<float>>`. Please check also the
[vector reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

The input shall be saved in `std::string`, as it is very robust against input
error, e.g. characters instead of numbers, etc. Please have a look to the
[string reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

The idea of my code is to hold the `[1 2 3,4 5 6,7 8 9]` matrix input as string
and to submit it to some string manipulation using the methods
[string::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and
[string::substr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) to
cut the rows and subsequently the numbers out of the input string.

Every detected number is than converted from string to float using
[std::stof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof), before
it is stored by `push_back` into the final matrix.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std; // Should be avoided in real life C++ projects, but for samples ok

// Detect all numbers in one row and store it to a vector of floats (no error handling right now)
vector<float> getMatrixRowNum(const string& givenRow) // Hand row string over as const reference
{
    vector<float> ret;
    float myFloat;
    int startColIndex = 0;
    int endColIndex = 0;
    while ((endColIndex = givenRow.find(' ', startColIndex)) != string::npos)
    {
        myFloat = stof(givenRow.substr(startColIndex, endColIndex - startColIndex));
        ret.push_back(myFloat);
        startColIndex = endColIndex + 1;
    }
    myFloat = stof(givenRow.substr(startColIndex, endColIndex - startColIndex));
    ret.push_back(myFloat);
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    string matrixInput;
    vector<vector<float>> myMatrix; // STL container for parsed matrix (std::vector)
    cout << "Give a matrix in format [1 2 3,4 5 6,7 8 9]:" << endl;
    getline(cin, matrixInput);
    if (!matrixInput.empty() && matrixInput[0] == '[' && matrixInput.back() == ']')
    {
        cout << "Given matrix to parse: " << matrixInput << endl;
        string matrixTemp = matrixInput.substr(1, matrixInput.length() - 2);

        // Start parsing the given matrix string
        string matrixRow;
        int startRowIndex = 0;
        int endRowIndex = 0;
        while ((endRowIndex = matrixTemp.find(',', startRowIndex)) != string::npos)
        {
            matrixRow = matrixTemp.substr(startRowIndex, endRowIndex - startRowIndex);
            startRowIndex = endRowIndex + 1;
            auto matrixRowNum = getMatrixRowNum(matrixRow);
            myMatrix.push_back(matrixRowNum);
        };
        matrixRow = matrixTemp.substr(startRowIndex);
        auto matrixRowNum = getMatrixRowNum(matrixRow);
        myMatrix.push_back(matrixRowNum);

        // Write the parsed matrix to console output
        cout << "\nParsed numerical matrix:" << endl;
        for (const auto& row : myMatrix)
        {
            for (const auto& ele : row)
            {
                cout << ele << ' ';
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Wrong matrix format given: " << matrixInput << " Please try again." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The console output looks like this:

> Give a matrix in format [1 2 3,4 5 6,7 8 9]:
> [1 2 3,4 5 6,7 8 9]
> Given matrix to parse: [1 2 3,4 5 6,7 8 9]
>
> Parsed numerical matrix:
> 1 2 3
> 4 5 6
> 7 8 9

Some input error handling is added in the code, but it still could be improved, e.g. catching exceptions
for `std::stof`.